# What datatype in oracle would map to a Java int?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, oracle10g

What type in Oracle (10 Express Edition) would be the "same" as a Java int?

Comment: Good question - when I create a table with "INTEGER", it appears to convert it to "NUMBER(22)", and that can store numbers bigger than MAX_INT.

Comment: You could use a NUMBER. However, Make sure that you don't read it as an Object - the JDBC driver might actually produce a Double.

Comment: @Uri Not an issue when using JPA.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Java's int has a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 - so Number(10,0) is as close as you're going to get...

Comment: And, if appropriate, you can add a check constraint to the column, `check (column_name between -2147483648 and 2147483647)` to make sure the data stored does not fall outside of the range that the application can handle.

Comment: shouldn't this be NUMBER(9,0)?  With NUMBER(10,0) you could have a value (e.g. 9,999,999,999) that would exceed the range of a Java int.

Comment: No - then you wouldn't be covering the whole of the int type's range.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say `number(10,0)`.

Answer (score 1):

try NUMBER  . In Oracle we use Number for Integer